# FCM legacy http throw random (502) Bad Gateway exception

Tags: c#, google-cloud-platform, google-api, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have an Asp.net that makes about ~100K requests/day on FCM legacy HTTP end point
**https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send**

But every day about 500 randomly requests throw (502) Bad Gateway, and if I tried these requests manually after a while it works and the notification arrives.

Error I get:

```
Error 502 (Server Error)!!1
<p><b>502.</b>
<ins>That’s an error.</ins>
<p>The server encountered a temporary error and could not complete your request.<p>Please try again in 30 seconds.  
<ins>That’s all we know.</ins>
```

Requests that sometimes throw exceptions:

```
{
   "registration_ids":[
      "token 1",
      "token 2"
   ],
   "data":{
      "type":"navigation",
      "routeName":"Order",
      "Id":"18360"
   },
   "notification":{
      "title":"New Order Placed Successfully",
      "body":"Click here for more details #8073",
      "badge":1,
      "sound":"default"
   }
}
```

Best regards

Comment: Check memory on machine. See : https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/502-bad-gateway-randomly-ocurring

Comment: @jdweng in my case I think it's different because I'm getting a response from google

Comment: Link is also getting a response since the 502 is in the response.  If no response occurred an exception would occur indicating no response. or a timeout.

Comment: I'm getting this same error from time to time, after a few retries it works. I don't think memory is an issue here (502 is a server error, not a client error).

Comment: @thijsonline actually i have migrated to http v1 and the issue disappeared, i think google do that to encourage people to migrate to the new api version

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Migration to Http v1 solve the issue.

Migration guid:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/migrate-v1

Caution: Any apps that use device group messaging must continue to use the legacy API for the management of device groups (creating, updating, etc.). The HTTP v1 can send messages to device groups, but does not support management.

Comment: Just got this error on the HTTP v1 Endpoint as well using HTTP/2 multiplexing. A workaround is to implement a retry mechanism, since it's a temporary server-side error at Google's end.